# _segment not defined wile migrate from VC6 to VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I'm migrating a Windows project from VC6 to VS2019, but I get an error:

> E0020 identifier "_segment" is undefined

I try to find _segment definition but no luck. So, I'm wondering if it is possible _segment is a keyword in VC6. However, I still find nothing in Google.

Any idea how to fix the error? Thanks.

The code is:

```
#ifndef _MSC_Ver
#define _MSC_Ver
#endif

/* MS-C  ?? */
#ifdef  _MSC_VER
_segment SegDefine,SegType,SegSym,SegCode;
#endif

#define ALLOC_C
#include "common.h"
#include <malloc.h>
#include "extern.h"

#ifdef  MSDOS
#include <dos.h>
#ifndef __WATCOMC__
#include <memory.h>
#endif
#endif

/* MM(????)?    */
#define MaxClass    8

#ifdef  _MSC_VER    /* MS-C  ?? */

/* FARBased ? */
static USHORT       mmFarSeg[MaxClass];         /* ??         */
static USHORT       mmFarBase[MaxClass];        /*          */
static USHORT       mmFarOrg[MaxClass];         /* ??        */
static USHORT       mmFarSize[MaxClass];        /*          */
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`_segment` was a keyword in 16-bit MSC 6 and VC 1.x (*not* VC 6), related to the [x86 memory segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation) and `_based` pointers. The keyword was retired in 32-bit versions of VC, starting with VC 2.0. From Microsoft's [Q67882](https://github.com/jeffpar/kbarchive/tree/master/kb/067/Q67882):

> *The following keywords were first introduced with Microsoft C version 6.0:*
>
> `_based`
>
> `_segment`
>
> [...]
>
> *NOTE: In Microsoft Visual C++ 32-bit Edition, version 2.0, the `_segment` keyword
> was removed and the functionality of the `__based` keyword changed.*

Comment: Is there a keyword in VS2019 corresponding to it? If not, what can I replace _segment with? Thanks!

Comment: @David There is no corresponding keyword, because there are no longer any "*segments*" to speak of in the flat memory models used in 32- and 64-bit nowadays. VC++ still supports [based pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/based-pointers-cpp?view=msvc-160), though they have rather specialized uses. Whether it makes better sense to fully rewrite vs. drop altogether the 16-bit code that used `_segment` addressing cannot be answered without fully understanding what the old code was doing in the first place.

Comment: Wish the belated downvoter had left a comment why.